# Lambda in one security group cannot talk to RDS in another security group in a peered VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-security-group, aws-vpc-peering

Here's my architecture:

1. My Lambda in Lambda_VPC with SecurityGroup (Lambda_SG);
2. My RDS in RDS_VPC with SecurityGroup (RDS_SG);
3. I've created a peering connection with Lambda_VPC and RDS_VPC called `peering_cxn`;
4. I've modified the route tables for both Lambda_VPC and RDS_VPC to include this `peering_cxn` following this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-routing.html);
5. I've added Lambda_SG as one of the inbound rules in RDS_SG on port 8192 with custom TCP as traffic type
6. DNS resolution enabled on both VPCs;

But somehow my lambda still cannot call RDS, it keeps timing out.

A couple things to note:

1. The endpoint and credentials that my Lambda uses to connect with RDS is correct as I was able to confirm the connection after briefly adding 0.0.0.0/0 as one of the inbound rules for RDS_SG. Of course I don't want to resort to 0.0.0.0/0 as a resolution as it opens our system to the whole internet and protected only by the DB credentials;
2. Also, I'm able to connect to this RDS instance via exactly the same credentials through a SQLClient directly from my Macbook.

Based on my understanding, with this peering VPC in the same account in the same region, Lambda_SG added as an inbound rule for RDS_SG, it should be working, but it's not yet.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

1. I launched an EC2 instance in Lambda_VPC with Lambda_SG, connected to this EC2 instance and tried to connect to RDS:

```
sh-5.2$ telnet cluster-abc.cluster-abc987-dbd.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 8192
Trying 12.345.398.11...
telnet: connect to address 12.345.398.11: Connection timed out
```

2. I've gone into DNS settings of the peering connection and checked both boxes to:

```
1. Allow accepter VPC (Lambda_VPC) to resolve DNS of requester VPC (RDS_VPC) hosts to private IP.
2. Allow requester VPC (RDS_VPC) to resolve DNS of accepter VPC (Lambda_VPC) hosts to private IP.
```

UPDATE 2:
`12.345.398.11` is a public IP address, indicating it didn't try to resolve to a private address as DNS propogation takes time.
So after one night, I connected with the ec2 instance and tried to connect RDS again:

```
sh-5.2$ telnet cluster-abc.cluster-abc987-dbd.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 8192
Trying 10.0.41.180...
telnet: connect to address 10.0.41.180: Connection timed out
```

This time, this IP: `10.0.41.180` is within the CIDR range of the RDS_VPC of: `10.0.0.0/16`. But still timed out.

Comment: Just edited my OP to make it more explicit, please let me know if you need more info, thanks!

Comment: Test by connecting telnet or your DB client to private-ip:8192. If that works, you know it's DNS.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the connection works when RDS_SG allows incoming traffic from `0.0.0.0/0` but not from `Lambda_SG` suggests that the connection is being made to the Amazon RDS instance's **private IP address**. If so, then the Security Group will not recognise the incoming connection as coming from Lambda_SG because the traffic has gone out of Lambda_VPC via the Internet rather than the VPC Peering Connection.

To confirm this, you can attempt to resolve the RDS instance's DNS name within Lambda_VPC.

To resolve it, you will need to **enable private DNS resolution**.

From [Enable DNS resolution for a VPC peering connection - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/modify-peering-connections.html):

> To enable a VPC to resolve public IPv4 DNS hostnames to private IPv4 addresses when queried from instances in the peer VPC, you must modify your existing peering connection.
>
> Both VPCs must be enabled for DNS hostnames and DNS resolution.
>
> ...
>
> To ensure that queries from the peer VPC resolve to private IP addresses in your local VPC, choose the option to enable DNS resolution for queries from the peer VPC. This option is **Requester DNS resolution** or **Accepter DNS resolution**, depending on whether the VPC is the requester or accepter VPC.

Once this is activated, your existing configuration should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked both boxes in my peering connection: Allow accepter VPC (Lambda_VPC) to resolve DNS of requester VPC (RDS_VPC) hosts to private IP, but the issue still persists.

Comment: And how can I do this: `To confirm this, you can attempt to resolve the RDS instance's DNS name within Lambda_VPC`. I tried to connect to this RDS instance from an EC2 instance launched in Lambda_VPC, but timed out, I posted details in my OP.

Comment: Your `telnet` command is resolving the DNS name to `12.345.398.11`, which is a **public IP address**. This confirm the cause of the problem -- it is attempting to connect via a public IP address instead of a private IP address and the Security Group cannot provide the security you have requested. Perhaps it just takes a bit of time for the DNS change to take effect, but basically you need that `telnet` command to return an IP address that is in the range of RDS_VPC.

Comment: Ok, after one night, when I ran `sh-5.2$ telnet cluster-abc.cluster-abc987-dbd.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 8192
Trying 10.0.41.180...
telnet: connect to address 10.0.41.180: Connection timed out
` This IP: 10.0.41.180 is truly within the range of the CIDR block of RDS_VPC: 10.0.0.1/16, but still timed out..

Comment: Excellent, that's progress! Are you sure that port 8192 is the correct port for your database? It's an unusual number. Next, try changing the Inbound rule on the Security Group to accept incoming connections from `10.0.0.0/16`, which is Lambda_VPC. Since it is working for you on `0.0.0.0/0`, it's just a matter of figuring out which IP address it is 'coming from' with a bit of trial-and-error.

Comment: Yes, 8192 is for sure, as I said earlier, I was able to use the endpoint along with this port number to connect to RDS via my MacBook SQLClient. `10.0.0.0/16` is actually my RDS_VPC.

Comment: I have both RDS_VPC and Lambda_VPC CIDR blocks added as inbound_rules in my RDS_SG, still timed out.

Comment: Oops, yes it should allow from the Lambda_VPC CIDR. If the Security Group is open to the CIDR associated with Lambda_VPC, then the `telnet` from your EC2 instance should be able to make a connection. If you temporarily change it to `0.0.0.0/0`, does the telnet work on 10.0.41.180? Also make sure that the NACLs are set to their default "Allow All" configuration.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, adding `0.0.0.0/0` in my RDS_SG inbound rules didn't help: `telnet` to this private IP address still timed out.

Comment: So, can you get it back to any condition where it does work, as you originally mentioned in your Question?